# MS Word - find all double spaces NOT after period

Tags: regex, ms-word

How would I FIND and REPLACE all double spaces that do NOT come after a period in word?

I have a document (100+ pages) where every now and then there is a sentence like

This[space]is[space]another[space][space]word[space]in[space][space]a[space]sentence.

I want to remove those two double spaces easily.  So far, using wild cards, I have been able to select them and I would replace with a single space, BUT the way "find" finds the words, it'll include the last letter of the word before two spaces.  Here's the find wildcard search:

```
([!.  ])[  ]{2,}
```

But, in the above example sentence, it'll higlight "r[space][space]" .  How do I replace that with just two spaces?  Using the replace

```
[space]
```

will remove the "r" from that word.  I just want to find the two spaces and replace that with one.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to Find `"([!.])[ ]{2}"` and replace with `"\1 "` (no double quotation marks).

```
*Input*: "This is another  word in  a sentence.  There is another one here."

*Output*: "This is another word in a sentence.  There is another one here."
```

Comment: Hm, it finds correctly, but when found the last letter of the word is still highlighted.  In your example "input" sentence, the first find would have "r  " highlighted, instead of just the double space between "another" and "word".

Comment: Yes, it will highlight as the symbol is in the Find expression. However, it won't be replaced as we can copy it back with `\1`. It is impossible not to highlight that since there is no lookbehind support in MS Office wildcards, and `(?<![.])[ ]{2}` raises `The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid.` exception. I think a macro could be used for it though. Are you interested in a VBA solution?